# Use angular material to make a popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have the following code that opens up a pop up and displays information returned by the function //showDetails(Data.path)// when we click on the icon.

```
  <a ng-show="Data.path" ng-click="showDetails(Data.path)">

      <ng-md-icon icon="info" style="fill: green" size="15"></ng-md-icon>
 </a>
```

I want the data to appear in a md-dialog modal window. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a controller which tells $mdDialog what it needs to do when the `showDetails(...)` function is triggered.

See: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog (Click "View Source" `<>` icon, and then switch to the "JS" tab to see an example of controller code to use; or just go straight to the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adeqVK)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-include for your modal, remember Angular creates a new child scope for it. You can acess the data in the modal using the following in your modal HTML:

```
{{$parent.Data.path}}
```